# jupyter notebook pyspark sparkmagic error when I use inline sql magic

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, livy

I have successfully configured PySpark kernel in jupyter notebook, I also installed SparkMagic.
When I try to use the below command:

```
%%sql
SELECT DepDelay, ArrDelay FROM flightData
```

it starts working and suddenly Spark stops throwing the below error:

> An error was encountered: Invalid status code '400' from
>   http://localhost:8998/sessions/0/statements/4 with error payload:
>   {"msg":"requirement failed: Session isn't active."}

you can find the full log file here to download and take a look.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lvYqQBUCiIFp4lz3aVnzMgBNd9fzqJiz

Appreciate your help. 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: before running this line, are you sure that a connection is established, if not try spark.applicationID

Comment: everything else works, for example: the next lines, so i guess the application is running. data.createOrReplaceTempView("flightData")
spark.sql("SELECT DayOfWeek, AVG(ArrDelay) AS AvgDelay FROM flightData GROUP BY DayOfWeek ORDER BY DayOfWeek").show()

Answer (score 0):

Try in a single line like this

```
%sql SELECTDepDelay, ArrDelay FROM flightData
```

Comment: This did now work, however, I loaded a smaller number of rows into the data frame and the command "%%sql" worked, so I guess it's related to my PC's resources, are there any configurations that could be done?